# Map coordinates of schools across the UK to an existing shapefile

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I have a pre--existing `shapefile` of the UK that has been provided to me. I have a separate csv file that has the longitude and latitudes of all the schools I want to map onto the `shapefile`.

```
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_polygon(data=polys.df.phec, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=NA), color = "black", fill=NA, size=0.5) 
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=subset_practice, aes(x=lon, y=lat, color="red"),inherit.aes = FALSE)
gg <- gg +  coord_map()
gg
```

I have successfully managed to get the map of the UK as the plot

```
 ls()

 head(polys.df.phec)

 map13 <- ggplot(data = polys.df.phec, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))

 map13 + geom_path()
```

I expected to get the data points on the map, but i get an error saying "Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one." and

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'lon' not found

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a reproducible example for others to help. Your objects `polys.df.phec` and `subset_practice` can't be used by anyone on StackOverflow to help answer your question as they are unique to your R session.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a reproducible example would help...in the meantime, here's some code I used when learning how to map lat/long points on a shapefile.

```
ggmap(sydmap2) +
  geom_point(data = crime, aes(x = bcsrgclng, y = bcsrgclat), color = "purple4", alpha=.03, size=1.1) +
  #ggtitle("Sydney Outdoor Crime") +
  labs(title = "Sydney Outdoor Crime", x = "", y = "") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 24), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(),
axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

Essentially I'm calling the map shapefile in the `ggmap()` statement, then using `geom_point()` to identify the dataset with the lat/long coordinates. The other calls are for coloring the dots, formatting the axes, etc...

It's code modified from [this tutorial](https://rpubs.com/JuanPabloHA/MapsVignetteJP) that I found helpful in learning mapping basics.